# CPU usage fluctuation with a parallel job on HPC clusters

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, cpu

At our university we have 2 HPC clusters dedicated for running quantum chemical calculations. One is old (since 2009), and the newer one was installed a couple of weeks ago. Each computing blade in the old and new cluster systems has 16 processors. The same program is installed on both clusters and works with OpenMpi 1.6.5. On the old cluster, the processor usage of each blade is steady at 100 % and looks like that:

[image: CPU usage on one of the computing blades on the old HPC cluster]

Now when running the exact same calculation on a computing blade of the new cluster, the CPU usage is fluctuating all the time between 0 and 100 % and in most of the time looks something like this:

[image: CPU usage on one of the computing blades on the new HPC cluster]

Calculations on the old cluster, even though the processors are of an older generation and of less power, finish in much lesser time than the ones started on the new cluster. 
Both cluster systems are running RedHat linux enterprise

What could be the problem here? and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: Please provide your `mpirun` command and your threading library. If you're using OpenMP for threading, what is the value for `OMP_NUM_THREADS` on each environment?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with this but I know that no threading was definied when compiling openmpi on both systems, which would suggest one thread per CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. I figured I'd post it here to help anyone who might encounter the same issue.
On the new cluster, the one with the CPU frequency issue, the calculation was run directly on the /home partition which is connected to each computing blade via NFS (network file system). This dramatically slowed down the calculation and caused the low CPU frequency issue and high waiting time, probably due to the fact that a lot of recourses are used to make the constant connection between the blade and the /home directory.
When I modified the script to make the calculations run in a temporary folder inside each blade, the problem was solved.